# Custom html helpers dont work in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have just installed MVC3 and VS 2010 express.

Writing my first app in MVC3 but not my first MVC app.

I have written a custom html helper like so

```
namespace MyNamespace.Web.Helpers
{

    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static string RenderHeaderImages(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder();
            List<string> files = (List<string>)HttpContext.Current.Application["HeaderImages"];

            bldr.AppendLine("<table><tr>");
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                bldr.AppendLine(string.Format("<td><img class=\"headerImage\" src=\"{0}/Content/Images/Header/{1}\", alt=\"{2}\" /></td>"
                    , HtmlExtensions.GetAppPath(""),  file, file));
            }
            bldr.AppendLine("</table></tr>");

            return bldr.ToString();
        }

        public static string GetAppPath(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            return HtmlExtensions.GetAppPath("");
        }

        public static string GetAppPath(this HtmlHelper html, string arg)
        {
            return HtmlExtensions.GetAppPath(arg);
        }

        public static string GetAppPath(string arg)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.ToString() == @"/")
                return "http://localhost:50194" + arg;
            else
                return HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath.ToString() + arg;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried adding "using" to my razor view and also adding namepsace to the views/webconfig file.

```
@using MyNamespace.Web.Helpers

<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="MyNamespace.Web.Helpers"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

But still the helper does not work.

And it does not come up in intellisense.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is bugged. Try to recompile/restart VS.. I had problem with this too, but eventually it started working on its own. And do not return string, but `MvcHtmlString` (or any other `IHtmlString` implementation, but `MvcHtmlString` has implemented `MvcHtmlString.IsNullOrEmpty`, so I'd recommend that) - if you return just string, `@Html.RenderHeaderImages` will encode all html tags. Another thing would be that `Html.RenderXXX` usually writes directly to output and returns void, so better name for this would be just `HeaderImages`.

Comment: And it doesn't work as long as you haven't successfully compiled it (unlike normal code that appears in Inttlisense as soon as you have written it).

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem where my custom HTML helper was not being found. I thought it was enough to put the helper's namespace in web.config. But you also need the using statement inside your view (I'm using razor):

```
@using MyProject.HtmlHelpers;
```

Thanks for posting this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I added the wrong `using` for the `HtmlHelper` class

```
using System.Web.WebPages.Html;
```

should have been

```
using System.Web.Mvc
```