# Why is this checkbox[list] returning 1 or false?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

When I checked both checkboxes, I get "1". When I check the first checkbox, I get "1". When I check only the second checkbox, I get "false". Why is that? And also, how do I get the other checkbox to post its value (or at all)? The code and resulting HTML below.

```
@model InspectionWebFormsMVC.ViewModels.CtrlInputDataModel

@{
    var ddv = new SelectList(Model.RowCtrl.DefaultValues, "Value", "Label");

    switch (Model.RowCtrl.Type)
    {
        case "checkbox":
            foreach (var sli in ddv)
            {
                @Html.LabelFor(blah => blah.InputtedData, sli.Text)

                bool isChecked = false;
                string attrChecked = "checked";
                if (Model.InputtedData == sli.Value){
                    isChecked = true;
                    @Html.CheckBox("InputtedData", isChecked, new { @value = sli.Value, @checked = attrChecked })
                }
                else {
                    isChecked = false;
                    @Html.CheckBox("InputtedData", isChecked, new { @value = sli.Value })
                }


            }
                @Html.HiddenFor(blah => blah.InputtedDataID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(blah => blah.RowCtrl.CtrlTypeID)

                <br />
        break;
    }
}
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<label  for="sectionRows_a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b__RowInput_0__InputtedData">Red</label>

<input  id="sectionRows_a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b__RowInput_0__InputtedData" 
        name="sectionRows[a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b].RowInput[0].InputtedData" 
        type="checkbox" 
        value="1" />

<input  name="sectionRows[a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b].RowInput[0].InputtedData" 
        type="hidden" 
        value="false" />

<label  for="sectionRows_a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b__RowInput_0__InputtedData">Super</label>

<input  checked="checked" 
        id="sectionRows_a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b__RowInput_0__InputtedData" 
        name="sectionRows[a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b].RowInput[0].InputtedData" 
        type="checkbox" 
        value="2" />

<input  name="sectionRows[a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b].RowInput[0].InputtedData" 
        type="hidden" 
        value="false" />

<input  data-val="true" 
        data-val-number="The field InputtedDataID must be a number." 
        data-val-required="The InputtedDataID field is required." 
        id="sectionRows_a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b__RowInput_0__InputtedDataID" 
        name="sectionRows[a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b].RowInput[0].InputtedDataID" 
        type="hidden" 
        value="5" />

<input  data-val="true" 
        data-val-number="The field CtrlTypeID must be a number." 
        data-val-required="The CtrlTypeID field is required." 
        id="sectionRows_a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b__RowInput_0__RowCtrl_CtrlTypeID" 
        name="sectionRows[a7d91de2-c828-4cd4-979d-783caf85ae3b].RowInput[0].RowCtrl.CtrlTypeID" 
        type="hidden" 
        value="5" />
```

Comment: [The ongoing saga....](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11370640/428757)

Answer (score 0):

1. When multiple input elements share the same `name`, only the first one is posted at all.
2. When checkboxes are not checked, they do not post anything.

So when you have the first checkbox checked, you get "1". Everything after it is ignored.
When you don't have the first checkbox, the hidden field posts "false". Everything after it is ignored.

If you're wondering where the hidden fields come from, MVC helpers create a hidden field with the same name and the value `false` because of #2 above. Checkboxes are supposed to represent booleans, and so they wanted to always post true/false, instead of value/(nothing).

Comment: So how do I get my second checkbox to post "2"?

Comment: You can't, only true/false. Or more specifically 1/false. It may be labelled 2, but will still return true/false as a value.

Comment: You can either switch to radio buttons, which sounds like what you want, or you can not use the helpers. But remember that even without the hidden fields, if you have them both checked only the "1" will be posted.